# Add in True or False into a CAST function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

First post here so hopefully I'm giving enough info.  I'm using SQL server 2012 and trying to get this cast to return True.

When I run this I get values that are true and false, how can I make it to where it only returns true?

Thanks,

```
CAST(CAST(ProductLang.XMLData AS XML)
          .query('data(/genxml/checkbox/connection)'
         ) AS VARCHAR(50)
    ) AS [In Connection]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can't the `where` clause filter the rows with `false`?

Comment: I want to only return values that are true.  Right now when I run that bit of code it returns both True and False values.  I want to show only True values in my table and leave out the False values.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: what have you try in the `WHERE`?  what you mean isnt working?  The solution is on the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try:

```
WHERE CAST(CAST(ProductLang.XMLData AS XML)
                  .query('data(/genxml/checkbox/connection)'
               ) AS VARCHAR(50)
          ) = 'true'
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `true` to do in the context of SQL Server?

Comment: When I run that I get an error message.  "Invalid column name 'true'"

Comment: @canon OP say that cast return 'true'.

Comment: @canon.  I writing this out to use as query.  I am just testing it in SQL server.  I apologize, I should have stated that.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help everyone!